# How can I rotate around local axis? [Directx]

Tags: rotation, directx-9

I want to rotate my cube around x and y, z axis in local space. But if I use `D3DXMatrixRotation()`, and I rotate around y after x axis , it still rotates in world space. How can I rotate an object in local space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical setup is for transformation is:

```
world * view * projection
```

The *world* matrix converts from local (i.e. model) space to world space, so changing the world matrix is going to result in a new world space location.

Do you perhaps mean that you want a rotation about a different point than the origin in local space?

PS: Note that `D3DXMatrixRotation*` is for legacy D3DXMath. You should look at using [DirectXMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx) or perhaps the [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) wrapper for it in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK).